# laravel how to revert only last items deleted by soft delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, soft-delete

i have cart table that save all customer orders in there.

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| id | user_id | product | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

when user soft delete we want to soft delete all items in his cards

when user want to revert we want to revert those items that soft deleted in last time

i can implement it.

this is revert function in my code:

```
public function revertBackDeletedItems(Request $request)
{
    $user = apiGetUser();
    if ($user == null) {
        return apiAbort(401);
    }

    $purchaseCartCount = $user->cart()->onlyTrashed()->count();
    if ($purchaseCartCount == 0) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'no items in card '
        ];
    }

    $purchaseCartDateTimeInLatestDelete = $user->cart()->onlyTrashed()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()['deleted_at'];

    $purchaseCarts = PurchaseCart::onlyTrashed()->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('deleted_at', $purchaseCartDateTimeInLatestDelete)->get();
    foreach ($purchaseCarts as $key => $purchaseCart) {
        $purchaseCart->restore($purchaseCart->id);
    }
    return ['success' => true];
}
```

this is the function that delete only the last time items that was deleted?

```
 public function deleteLastTrashed(Request $request)
{
    $user = apiGetUser();
    if ($user == null) {
        return apiAbort(401);
    }

    $purchaseCartCount = $user->cart()->onlyTrashed()->count();
    if ($purchaseCartCount == 0) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'no items in card '
        ];
    }

    $purchaseCartDateTimeInLatestDelete = $user->cart()->onlyTrashed()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()['deleted_at'];

    $purchaseCarts = PurchaseCart::onlyTrashed()->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('deleted_at', $purchaseCartDateTimeInLatestDelete)->get();
    foreach ($purchaseCarts as $key => $purchaseCart) {
        $purchaseCart->forceDelete($purchaseCart->id);
    }
    return ['success' => true];
}
```

how can i get deleted_at in better way?

this is not a clean code?

i need better way to implement this algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got there:

```
public function deleteLastTrashed(Request $request)
{
    $user = apiGetUser();
    if ($user == null) {
        return apiAbort(401);
    }

    $purchaseCartCount = $user->cart()->onlyTrashed()->count();
    if ($purchaseCartCount == 0) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'no items in card '
        ];
    }

    // here you know that user has at least one soft deleted cart
    $userLastCartSoftDeleted = $user->cart()->onlyTrashed()->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')->first();

    $userLastCartSoftDeleted->forceDelete();

    return ['success' => true];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your could try this:

**Add new fields in carts table is_deleted and is_recent so whenever user will delete set is_deleted = 1; and is_recent = 1 to that item which you are going to delete and rest of other is_recent = 0;
During revert fetch that items which have is_recent = 1; and save is_deleted = 1**